# Regular expression to select a sentence with particular length

Tags: regex, r

I need to extract a sentence from a block of text containing a particular word. This one I have:

```
[A-Z][^\\.;\\?\\!]*(word)[^\\.;\\?\\!]*
```

But I also need this sentence to be a particular length, say between 30 and 250 symbols. I know this seems to be easy, but I can't get how to do this.

So the input could be:

```
Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by gskinner.com, proudly **hosted** by Media Temple! A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial hosted by Media Temple which are so amazingly awesome that just looking at the name I get a boner instantly, and I am really serious right now, it's that exciting if you didn't get it.
```

The text above contains 2 sentences: One is 76 symbols and another is 266. Both contain word **hosted**, which would be our word of choice. So the regex should match the first sentence. And the output should be:

```
Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by gskinner.com, proudly **hosted** by Media Temple
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a fairly difficult problem, especially since we don't have any context. Please provide a sample of what your text block looks like. An example of difficulty: abbreviations such as U.S. for the United States.

Comment: It's also difficult because regex in R has very limited capabilities. You might do better just checking the length of the match it finds.

Comment: As an input I use fiction literature. Let's say for this example it can be Hemingway, "For whom the bell tolls".

Comment: @4castle, but if it doesn't fit, how do I start regex again? I mean I can use str_locate from stringr, but how do I start from a preferred position?

Comment: Please post a clear ***INPUT*** and desired ***OUTPUT*** sample

Comment: There is no mention of R anywhere in the question.  Is this an R question?  It's tagged as such.

Comment: @RichardScriven interesting plot twist

Comment: A little fyi - Problem #1: you can't parse Language with Regular Expressions, it's impossible. Problem #2: If you want to _kludge_ past problem 1, inside a regex, there is no way to align the length of the match with any reference point in which the _word_ will be contained, without counting, which regex can't do. It can be done in Perl using _code_ constructs, but then you have to know Perl. The best you can do is klude a match, then check it's length after the match. Sorry for the bad news ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using English texts to parse.

You can use NLP library to split text into sentences, and then only take those that contain `word` and are of specific length. I used Earnest Hemingway biography excerpt from the Wikipedia, and used the word "1970" to extract and then applied a second `grep` to only have a length-restricted value.

```
> require(tm)
> require(openNLP)
> text <- as.String("Ernest Hemingway wrote For Whom the Bell Tolls in Havana, Cuba; Key West, Florida; and Sun Valley, Idaho in 1939. In Cuba, he lived in the Hotel Ambos-Mundos where he worked on the manuscript. The novel was finished in July 1940 and published in October.It is based on Hemingway's experiences during the Spanish Civil War and features an American protagonist, named Robert Jordan, who fights with Spanish soldiers for the Republicans. The characters in the novel include those who are purely fictional, those based on real people but fictionalized, and those who were actual figures in the war. Set in the Sierra de Guadarrama mountain range between Madrid and Segovia, the action takes place during four days and three nights. For Whom the Bell Tolls became a Book of the Month Club choice, sold half a million copies within months, was nominated for a Pulitzer Prize, and became a literary triumph for Hemingway. Published on 21 October 1940, the first edition print run was 75,000 copies priced at $2.75.")
> sentence_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
> sentence.boundaries <- annotate(text, sentence_token_annotator)
> sentences <- text[sentence.boundaries]
> sentences
[1] "Ernest Hemingway wrote For Whom the Bell Tolls in Havana, Cuba; Key West, Florida; and Sun Valley, Idaho in 1939."                                                                                                                                   
[2] "In Cuba, he lived in the Hotel Ambos-Mundos where he worked on the manuscript."                                                                                                                                                                      
[3] "The novel was finished in July 1940 and published in October.It is based on Hemingway's experiences during the Spanish Civil War and features an American protagonist, named Robert Jordan, who fights with Spanish soldiers for the Republicans.[8]"
[4] "The characters in the novel include those who are purely fictional, those based on real people but fictionalized, and those who were actual figures in the war."                                                                                     
[5] "Set in the Sierra de Guadarrama mountain range between Madrid and Segovia, the action takes place during four days and three nights."                                                                                                                
[6] "For Whom the Bell Tolls became a Book of the Month Club choice, sold half a million copies within months, was nominated for a Pulitzer Prize, and became a literary triumph for Hemingway."                                                          
[7] "Published on 21 October 1940, the first edition print run was 75,000 copies priced at $2.75."                                                                                                                                                        
> with_word = grep("1940", sentences, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
> with_word
[1] "The novel was finished in July 1940 and published in October.It is based on Hemingway's experiences during the Spanish Civil War and features an American protagonist, named Robert Jordan, who fights with Spanish soldiers for the Republicans.[8]"
[2] "Published on 21 October 1940, the first edition print run was 75,000 copies priced at $2.75."                                                                                                                                                        
> with_word[grep("^.{30,100}$", with_word)]
[1] "Published on 21 October 1940, the first edition print run was 75,000 copies priced at $2.75."
```

In your case, use your own word and `{30,250}` limiting quantifier to get just those sentences you need.

Note that it is possible to grep the sentences you need with 1 operation, but you will need a more complex PCRE regex with a lookahead:

```
> my_sent <- grep("(?s)(?=.{30,100}$).*1940.*$", sentences, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> my_sent
[1] "Published on 21 October 1940, the first edition print run was 75,000 copies priced at $2.75."
```

The `"(?s)(?=.{30,100}$).*1940.*$"` regex will require the string to have 30 to 100 (set your own limits) characters from start to end, and the string should contain `1940` word (note that if your word contains special regex metacharacters, they must be escaped with `\\`).

Just tested with your data:

```
> with_word = grep("(?s)^(?=.{30,250}$).*\\bhosted\\b.*$", sentences, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
> with_word
[1] "proudly hosted by Media Temple!"
```

Comment: Dear Wiktor. This is marvellously fantastic! Several comments to the post convinced me that probably R is not the best tool to work with natural language text. But Ka-Boom! You showed me a proper plugin. And the whole solution to my problem. Which showed that I was not even close to the result. Thank you very much! And I beg your pardon for such a vague explanation in the post. However you understood it exactly. Btw, it took me 5 hours of workarounds to install openNLP, I had to downgrade Java and do many other things, that's why I am so late with the reply. Thank you, and have a great life :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?=[\p{Any}]{30,250}.*)
```

Comment: I beg your pardon, but as you could notice I am not really good at regular expressions. And I don't quite understand how I can use positive lookahead in this particular example. What is following what in our case?

Comment: Positive look-ahead will ensure the whatever comes next on the regex must match the positive look-ahead group. Let me take a look at your updated question.

Comment: How do we know where the first sentence ends ? Are they separated or on the same line ?

Comment: This approach will not work - it is impossible to mark the end of sentence correctly in the lookahead. Splitting the text into sentences and then `grep` is the only correct approach that I see here.

Comment: the OP posted the examples after my answer, then I asked "**How do we know where the first sentence ends ? Are they separated or on the same line ?**" and I'm still waiting for an answer. Your solution seems way more reliable indeed but the OP may have some specific sentences and positive look-ahead may work in conjunction with other regex